# XNA 4.0 Glowing objects

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to achieve a simple task (or so I thought) in XNA 4.0. I have objects that need to glow (rendering and Gaussian blurring them and then adding them to the main scene). These objects can be at different depths so I will need to make sure that they are obscured by objects in front of them in the main scene. It's 3D.

Because depth buffers cannot be re-used in XNA 4.0, I am having a hard time figuring out how I can achieve this?

I can find no examples or tutorials or explanations of this process. The bloom post process example of XNA also does not do exactly what I need, as it post processes the entire scene.

I know that I can preserve RenderTarget info by using PreserveContents, but it sounded like it was slow. Is there a way to achieve this without using PreserveContents?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you,
Riaan.

Comment: A visual example of what you want to do would be tremendously helpful. Can you mock something up?

Comment: Mmm. I can't seem to upload the image as I'm new. Here is a link to it: http://postimage.org/image/cwmw2cglh/a6790034/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'depth buffers cannot be reused'? XNA lets you do almost anything with depth buffers.

Comment: According to the Shawn, depth buffers cannot be shared between Render Targets (http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/64179/397431.aspx). As soon as you set a new rendertarget, the old RT's Depth Buffer is resolved automatically and cannot be used for further depth testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to render the glowing objects using a second rendertarget to store its depth... this is a multi target rendering technique...

I suppose that you will need another for the non glowing objects..(or use the same, storing both depths with an addtive blending) to compare them at postproccess time...

later in the post process it would be possible to know if the glowing object is visible or is hidden.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The question for me (I am probably missing something fundamental) is how do I re-use the depth information in the second RT. Is that information not discarded as soon as I switch to another RT?

Comment: you will have it as a texture

Comment: I know, but will the texture not contain all the glowing objects of the entire scene, even the ones that should actually be hidden by normal scene objects in front of them? Here is the scenario: Render scene to RT1, render glowing objects to RT2. RT1 contains the entire scene, RT2 contains all the glowing objects. How do you merge the glowing objects into the full scene without the depth info?

Comment: in the post proccess you can accces to the depth info texture and discard the pixels that are from non glowing objects

Comment: In post process, I need to comapare the depth info from the glowing pixel to that of the scene pixel at the same position (Should I choose to do it in post process). This means that I need the depth info of RT1 and RT2 to know which glowing pixels are visible and which are not... IF I am not mistaken, the Texture that I have for RT2 is only the image, not the depth info.

Comment: I see what you mean. Did some looking around and this might be what I need. Will it be a bad idea to be dependent on multiple render target support on the GPU? Or is it not a worry nowadays?

Comment: Deferred shading rendering technique is based in MRT, and it is a very used technique... though in old gpu it does not run...